# Script on media query/matchMedia

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a script (https://github.com/SubZane/flyPanels) that should only be executed on small devices.

The script is called by:

```
<script>
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    FastClick.attach(document.body);
    flyPanels.init({
            treeMenu: {
                init: true
            },
            search: {
                init: true,
                saveQueryCookie: true
            }
    })
});

</script>
```

How do i achieve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to identify screen size](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12195371/how-to-identify-screen-size)

Answer (score 0):

Refer this [link](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_screen.asp)

So basically you can check by an if statement like

```
if(screen.width == 768){
    //your code here

}
```

...and then have your event code under it.
Just inquire about the screen size you want your code to work and check for that.
PS: the screen object of js has specs in px....so make sure to check in px.